# "Droll" is to "amusing" as "sardonic" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, antonyms, analogy

Could someone solve this analogy?

```
droll : amusing :: sardonic : ________
```

P.S. the answer does not have to be a specific length.

Comment: Well, not all amusement is droll, and arguably not all drollery is amusing. But whatever the relationship between the two words is, I'm not sure it makes sense to generalise that relationship and apply it to another pair of words with vaguely related meanings. *Cent* is to *dollar* as *nickel* is to **what**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: $5, did you not do math? ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: *Fumble* is to *Finger* as *Grope* is to....?  ;-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Hmm, tough call, depends on your sliding scale and whether you think of groping as an involuntary thing and how well you get along with a fumble...  I would say *Rape* or *Serious Sexual Assault*, assuming the involuntary case.

Comment: My first thought was Captain Blood. Take from that what you will...

Comment: @kitukwfyer: I think that's *Blood* **Group**, not *Grope*.

Comment: @Fumble I was actual commenting on the question itself. When I saw "sardonic," I thought of Captain Blood. I just now realised where it falls in the comments...Whoooops. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since we do not have any options here, I would nominate *mocking* as the best answer.

Comment: Ditto from  me ...

Comment: *Mordant* or *sarcastic* would also fit the bill if we're looking for words with overtones of 'conversational wit', but that needn't be part of the relationship being transposed here. So you could just as well say *derisive*, *scathing*, *disdainful*, or whatever. Personally I don't see anything more than a long list of synonyms coming out of this Q, so I hope you'll understand if I don't upvote your answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Perhaps, but I think mocking fits better here. It is a direct parallel: one is droll to be amusing, and sardonic to be mocking; also, both *amusing* and *mocking* are progressive verb forms used as adjectives.

Comment: @Robusto: Ok, I take your point re *mocking*. Though I would say your purpose in being sardonic might not be to mock - you might just be expressing bitter cynicism. I still don't think the Q has (or should have) legs.

Comment: @Robusto: "It is a direct parallel: one is droll to be amusing, and sardonic to be mocking; also, both amusing and mocking are progressive verb forms used as adjectives." Thanks for providing the explanation I was too lazy to formulate. That was exactly my reasoning as well!

Comment: I still think it is a very unclear question. Jimi might be right; but, if we cannot come to an easy consensus, it can't be a good question.

Comment: @Cerberus: Oh, of course! Questions like this usually come with options, hence my *nomination*!

Comment: @inquisitive: You're welcome!

Comment: @JimiOke: I know, and you weren't giving the impression that you believed you had the definitive answer at all! I just wanted to add my voice to the confusion.

Comment: @Cerberus: Certainly! I heartily agreed with your previous comment.

Comment: @JimiOke: Hah, I think we are more than agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Pleasing or satisfying.

The primary definition of "sardonic" is "mocking," or "cynical." Since we need an adjective here, those would be the obvious go-to choices. Another possibility would be "praising," but that's a stretch.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning there at all. *Droll* : *Amusing* is (approximately) a relationship of equivalence. I'm having trouble conceptualising the relationship of *Sardonic* : *Pleasing*, but it certainly doesn't seem like an equivalence. Unless you really like burning people with your acid wit...